# Magento:move products and categories to another magento installation

Tags: magento

Is it possible to  move a set of products and categories from one magento installation to another, either replacing or adding to the 2nd installation catalog ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to export the products and categories data (products export is in a base Magento install, categories export is available by a third party module - santosh?), then import that data into your second installation. This will keep everything find and dandy with all of the data, indexes, etc.